# Restricting Special Characters from Character Map JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have all possible validations in my textbox which restricts user from entering any special character. But recently i experienced that a user can copy paste the special characters from Character Map which are in Windows. 
In my current code i have restricted special characters of keyboard in regular expression. 
But i couldn't find a way to restrict the special characters from Character Map, this lets the user to escape the last name and also make it look blank.

Comment: I have already stated, that i have existing validations saved in my regEx. For the special Characters from Character Map i havent tried and even i have no clue how to capture such events or restrict such type of Characters. To show the existing code of my existing validation i have no problem in that, But i suppose that wouldnt help anyone from JS guys.

Comment: @tkamath99: Did you try listening to "onpaste event"??

Comment: @MuraliNepalli Even if i call the on paste event, how can i recognize those characters ? Just like we can recognize the numbers, special characters on keyboard... I hope you got my point.. To store those special characters in a variable and then check, the List is too Huge

Comment: @MuraliNepalli I have finally found a way. I have stored those characters (Latin American) into an object and then used .match. There are ASCII Code for all of the Latin American chars. I will post a fiddle as an answer soon